# Remove and Add Gridpanel again fail with CheckboxModel in extjs4.1 and 4.2

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I have a panel with `layout: border`, that look like **http://jsfiddle.net/rpcbX/**

[image]

When i click `add` button on west region I with `removeAll` from center region and add something again, in this example i add and remove gridpanel.

But My gridpanel has `CheckboxModel`. And that can't remove after i add gridpanel again.
Follow bellow step u will see bug.

**1.** Run my app and click `add` button

**2.** Click `checkall` butoon on gridpanel

**3.** Click `add` button again

Now u will see the bug, the selection was selected and u can't click `checkall` button to working. Look like

[image]

I think when i click add button then center region will has a new gridpanel (new state)

How to fix that thank

p/s: i was test that on extjs4.2.1 and the result's worse. i can't click checkbox on row ( i think i was click that but graphic not change)

Here is my code i using with `add` button

```
                text: 'add',
                handler: function() {
                    panel.down('panel[region="center"]').removeAll();
                    var grid = new Example();
                    panel.down('panel[region="center"]').add(grid);
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You example doesn't work because you are adding instances to the prototype and those instances of store, selModel potentially columns will be shared across all the instances of `Example`.  Your example is hitting undefined behavior. Non primitives on the prototype is generally a bad thing and for some reason I see them on stackoverflow a lot.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10044215/reusing-same-component-in-extjs/10051476#10051476) is a more in depth explanation.

Doing this for `Example` should help fix your problem.

```
Ext.define('Example', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    title: 'Simpsons',
    initComponent: function() {
        Ext.apply(this, {
            selModel: Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel', {
                checkOnly: true,
                mode: 'MULTI'
            }),
            store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone'],
                data: {
                    'items': [{
                            'name': 'Lisa',
                            "email": "lisa@simpsons.com",
                            "phone": "555-111-1224"
                        }, {
                            'name': 'Bart',
                            "email": "bart@simpsons.com",
                            "phone": "555-222-1234"
                        }, {
                            'name': 'Homer',
                            "email": "home@simpsons.com",
                            "phone": "555-222-1244"
                        }, {
                            'name': 'Marge',
                            "email": "marge@simpsons.com",
                            "phone": "555-222-1254"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                proxy: {
                    type: 'memory',
                    reader: {
                        type: 'json',
                        root: 'items'
                    }
                }
            }),
            columns: [{
                    header: 'Name',
                    dataIndex: 'name',
                    editor: {
                        xtype: 'textfield'
                    }
                }, {
                    header: 'Email',
                    dataIndex: 'email',
                    flex: 1
                }, {
                    header: 'Phone',
                    dataIndex: 'phone'
                }
            ]
        });

        this.callParent();
    }

});
```